# How to use Codable and Coredata together?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, codable

I am trying to implement Codable with Coredata. I've tried following the following answer, but still have had no luck.

[How to use swift 4 Codable in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data/46917019#46917019)

The error/problem I am having is my project is continuing to say: "Argument type 'User' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable' whenever I try to encode or decode the object.

I have created the Entity in CoreData and made NSManagedObject subclasses:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(User)
public class User: NSManagedObject, Codable {

// MARK: - Codable setUp
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case fullname
    case email
    case zipcode
    case usertype = "user_type"
}


// MARK: - Decoding the data
required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) {
    guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else {NSLog("Error: with User context!")
        return
    }

    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context) else {
        NSLog("Error with user enity!")
        return
    }

    self.init(entity: entity, in: context)

    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    fullname = try values.decode(String.self, forkey: .fullname)
    email = try values.decode(String.self, forkey: .email)
    zipcode = try values.decode(String.self, forkey: .zipcode)
    userType = try values.decode(String.self, forkey: .userType)

}

// MARK: - Encoding the data
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = try encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    try container.encode(fullname, forkey: .fullname)
    try container.encode(email, forkey: .email)
    try container.encode(usertype, forkey: .usertype)
    try container.encode(zipcode, forkey: .zipcode)
}


}

// This helps with decoding
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
   static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")
}
```

When I try to decode the object and save the user to firebase I get a warning that says "In argument type 'User.Type', 'User' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'

[image]

When I try to encode I get a warning that says "Argument type 'User' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'

[image]

Comment: Your code gives different errors in a playground. It says your `init` and `encode` methods must be declared `public` because your User class is `public`. Are you not getting those errors?

Answer (score 0):

> User' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable

occurs due to a typo (case sensitivity matters):

`case usertype ...` vs. `...forKey: .userType)`

and the `encode/decode(:forKey:)` methods have a capital `K`

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem might not be related to CoreData/Codable, but rather to an imported User model, that in fact does not conform to Codable.

Firebase defines a `User` in their `FirebaseAuth.framework` ([Reference](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/ddc12c0fc194a30c792d23f12120ad0703859b73/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRUser.h#L58-L67)). If you `import Firebase` at the top of your file, it will also import that User declaration. IMO this is bad API design by Firebase, because many apps that also use FirebaseAuth will have a User model with some custom properties at some point...

If you don't need FirebaseAuth in that file, just import the more specific Firebase framework, e.g. `import FirebaseDatabase` to avoid importing their User model.

Otherwise, to help the compiler selecting your User model instead of the imported model, you can explicitly prepend `User.self` with your module name: `YourModule.User.self`.