# Codable CoreData models crash with `Unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Tags: swift, core-data, unrecognized-selector, codable

So, I'm in the midst of trying to conform my model classes to **NSManagedObject** (for CoreData persistence) and **Codable** (For JSON serialization/deserialization).  Right now my JSON decoder gets about halfway through deserialization before it crashes with the error

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Land setGun:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400028f780'`

I've been following the guide for conformance to both model protocols found here [How to use swift 4 Codable in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data) and I realize that the error is thrown because (if the error is to be believed) the Land class doesn't have a 'setGun' method.  What boggles me is

A) The error doesn't occur while I'm decoding Land class JSON (it handles that without a problem), the last breakpoint to be hit is actually in Sea class's JSON decoder.

B) The Land class DOES have a 'setGun' method (I declared a placeholder method in the class just to be extra sure in case it was something to do with the auto-generated CoreData code).

My code for the Land class is below:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
@objc(Land)
class Land : NSManagedObject, Equipment {
var type = EquipmentType.LAND

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name
    case desc = "description"
    case groupIconUrl
    case individualIconUrl
    case photoUrl
    case primaryWeapon
    case secondaryWeapon
    case atgm
    case armor
    case speed
    case auto
    case weight
}

required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    guard let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.context!] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError() }
    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Land", in: context) else { fatalError() }
    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    let container = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.id = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .id)
    self.name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.desc = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .desc)
    self.groupIconUrl = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .groupIconUrl)
    self.individualIconUrl = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .individualIconUrl)
    self.photoUrl = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .photoUrl)
    self.primaryWeapon = try container.decodeIfPresent(Gun.self, forKey: .primaryWeapon)
    self.secondaryWeapon = try container.decodeIfPresent(Gun.self, forKey: .secondaryWeapon)
    self.atgm = try container.decodeIfPresent(Gun.self, forKey: .atgm)
    self.armor = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .armor)
    self.speed = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .speed)
    self.auto = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .auto)
    self.weight = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .weight)
}
public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(desc, forKey: .desc)
    try container.encode(groupIconUrl, forKey: .groupIconUrl)
    try container.encode(individualIconUrl, forKey: .individualIconUrl)
    try container.encode(photoUrl, forKey: .photoUrl)
    try container.encode(primaryWeapon, forKey: .primaryWeapon)
    try container.encode(secondaryWeapon, forKey: .secondaryWeapon)
    try container.encode(atgm, forKey: .atgm)
    try container.encode(armor, forKey: .armor)
    try container.encode(speed, forKey: .speed)
    try container.encode(auto, forKey: .auto)
    try container.encode(weight, forKey: .weight)
}
public func setGun(gun: Gun){}
}
```

My CoreData dataModel is also screen-capped below:

[image: CoreData dataModel]

Finally, if all that isn't enough to diagnose what's going wrong, you're free to clone the repository and run it locally from the following public github repository: https://github.com/jamesjmtaylor/weg-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue in this lines at `Air.swift` file
I'm really don't know why don't decode Gun at Air file Decoder

```
self.gun = try container.decodeIfPresent(Gun.self, forKey: .gun)
self.agm = try container.decodeIfPresent(Gun.self, forKey: .agm)
self.aam = try container.decodeIfPresent(Gun.self, forKey: .aam)
self.asm = try container.decodeIfPresent(Gun.self, forKey: .asm)
```

Comment: Commenting out those lines (and `self.ceiling = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .ceiling)` allows it to compile and run.  But I need the Air model to have those attributes in order to work.  Any idea why it might not be decoding?  Or why it throws an error for the Land class and not the Air class where it's actually occuring?

Comment: I found it!  In the Air.swift file I had the line `guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Land", in: context) else { fatalError() }` . Replacing "Land" with "Air" fixed it.  Thank you!