# how to initialise variables in @NSManaged object class as a JSON value?

Tags: swift, core-data, swifty-json

I want to initialise the variables in the 'Item' class like the variables 'Item2' class

this is the 'Item' class :-

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import SwiftyJSON

class Item: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name = String()
    @NSManaged var symbol = String()
    @NSManaged var checked : Bool = false
    @NSManaged var buyPrice = String()
    @NSManaged var rank = String()

}
```

this is 'Item2' class :-

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class Item2 : Codable {

    var name = String()
    var symbol = String()
    var checked : Bool = false
    var buyPrice = String()
    var rank = String()

    init(bitJSON: JSON) {
        self.name       = bitJSON["name"].stringValue
        self.symbol     = bitJSON["symbol"].stringValue
        self.buyPrice   = bitJSON["price_usd"].stringValue
        self.rank       = bitJSON["rank"].stringValue
    }

}
```

Comment: `NSManagedObject` instances must be initialized with an `init` method which inserts the item in the managed object context. Basically it's possible with `Codable` and a custom initializer passing the managed object context in the `userInfo` dictionary of the decoder.

Comment: I made the 'Item' class codable and copy/paste the init method from class 'Item2' but it is saying '@NSManaged property cannot have an initial value'

Comment: This depends (also) on the definition of the Core Data model. But you should only declare the types of the `@NSManaged` properties without initial values according to the model

Comment: @vadian, Do you have example for using the model as codable where we can use the model for both coredata saving model and json parsing model ? I don't want create custom subclass for code data entity and separate model object. I want to use one (1) model class for both which can subclass both codable and nsmanagedobject or anything. In our old project, we used 2 models. And before converting we use mapper method to convert nsmanageobejct to nsobject (core data fetch) and nsobject to nsmanagedobejct (core data save). I was struggling for such example for somedays :(

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data/46917019#46917019

Answer (score 0):

ManagedObject are not normal object.  They are an object-oriented way to assess a database.  Managed objects use a context to get all their properties.  A managedObject must have context - they simply don't work without one.

```
extension Item {
    static func insert(json:JSON, in context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Item{
        let newItem = Item.init(entity: Item.entity(), insertInto:context)
        newItem.name       = json["name"].stringValue
        newItem.symbol     = json["symbol"].stringValue
        newItem.buyPrice   = json["price_usd"].stringValue
        newItem.rank       = json["rank"].stringValue
    }
}
```

Notice two things about this method: 1) it does not assume that it knows the context - that is a job for a higher level - for some apps it is simply inserted direclty into the viewContext, for other apps a temporary background context is created. and 2) it does not save the context - that is also not it's job - other object may be edited or created at the same time and they should all be save transactionally.

It would be used for example like this:

```
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
    let newItem = Item.insert(json: json, in: context)
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        // log to you analytic provider
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.