# Save a Struct to Core Data (NOT a CLASS)

Tags: swift, core-data

What is the best way to save a struct to core data currently I´m doning I this way but I´m not sure if it´s the best way or if theres is a better way:

```
import CoreData

@objc(SectionC)
public class SectionC: NSManagedObject {
  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SectionC> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SectionC>(entityName: "SectionC")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: Int16
    @NSManaged public var moduleId: Int16
}


struct Section: Codable {
    let id, moduleId: Int
}

static func save(sections: [Section], id: Int){
    for section in sections {
        if isExist(id: section.id, entity: SectionC.entityName){
            return
        }
        let sectionC = SectionC(context: context)
        sectionC.moduleId = Int16(id)
        sectionC.id = Int16(section.id)

        saveContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need two objects? just use the `NSManagedObject` it has a lot of features like canceling an unsaved changes.

Comment: cuase thats the way I figured out, Can you show an example how would you do it?

Comment: your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data)

Comment: the answered question is using a class not a struct

Comment: my suggestion was to use one object without the struct and `NSManagedObject` can not be a `struct`

Comment: Ok I get that, is there a way to acomplish what I want using a struct?