# Managing complex attributes in a class that extends both NSManagedObject and Codable

Tags: swift, core-data, codable

I have a class that extends both `NSManagedObject` and `Codable`. With this class I am attempting to have the app data saved on the iphone locally as well as have it convert from JSON to a Swift class object effortlessly.

The problem I am running into with my class is that I am getting an error while trying to write the `encode` function in my class:

```
`Reference to member 'arrayOfStrings' cannot be resolved without a contextual type`.
```

I've spent some time trying to fix this and have had no luck finding out what the actual problem is.

The problems are with two attributes that are of type `[String]` and `[Int]` respectively.

My class is declared as such in a file called `Foo+CoreDataClass.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Foo)
public class Foo: NSManagedObject, Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case arrayOfStrings
        case imageUrl
        case arrayOfInts
    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.context!] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("Some fatal error") }
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyManagedObject", in: context) else { fatalError() }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys.id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.name)
        self.arrayOfStrings = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: CodingKeys.arrayOfStrings) as NSObject
        self.imageUrl = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.imageUrl)
        self.arrayOfInts = try container.decode([Int].self, forKey: CodingKeys.arrayOfInts) as NSObject
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(arrayOfStrings, forKey: .arrayOfStrings)
        try container.encode(imageUrl, forKey: .imageUrl)
        try container.encode(arrayOfInts, forKey: .arrayOfInts)
    }
}

extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")
}
```

The other file that declares the properties are `Foo+CoreDataProperties.swift` defined as such:

```
extension Foo {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Foo> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Foo>(entityName: "Foo")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: Int
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var imageUrl: String?
    @NSManaged public var arrayOfStrings: NSObject?
    @NSManaged public var arrayOfInts: NSObject?
}
```

These files were created from within xcode when I when to the `Editor` tab and selected `Create NSManagedObject Subclass`.

I made the `Foo` class in `Foo+CoreDataClass.swift` inherit from `Codable` after following this post: [How to use swift 4 Codable in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data) along with these [Apple Docs on how to encode custom objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Has anyone successfully managed to use `NSManagedObject` and `Codable` with attributes that take the type of array? 
The goal that I am trying to achieve is to be able to convert between JSON and a CoreData object.

Edit: 
I am also having a problem with getting `Date` objects to encode correctly, the same error message as above is being shown.

Comment: What does `NSObject` represent?  I am as confused as the compiler.  Actually Core Data does not support arrays as attribute. You need a sort of mapping like a JSON string or something similar.

Comment: @vandian Hmm, those parameters were predefined when the class became created. If you would like to see what I mean this is the tutorial I was following when trying to add CoreData saving to my project: https://youtu.be/tP4OGvIRUC4?t=1062

Comment: Once again, *what does NSObject represent*? The tutorial uses standard attributes like `String` and `Int16`. And especially for Swift Xcode does not suggest the best (most efficient) types when creating the subclasses.

Comment: @vandian would it be correct to say an array of strings? I can see how `NSObject` is vague. And the JSON representation of the attribute is `arrayOfStrings` and that's why there is no mapping.

Comment: No, in terms of Core Data an array of *something* can only be represented as `Transformable` or serialized in one of the supported types (practically only `String`)

Comment: @vadian then you're referring to the type specified in the `.xcdatamodel`. `arrayOfStrings` is specified as a `Transformable`. How can I get this to correctly map for the encoder to be able to recognize it?

Comment: I'd recommend to declare both `arrayOfStrings` and `arrayOfInts` as `String` and use computed properties to map the values to JSON to become `Codable` compliant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186744/discussion-between-q-h-and-vadian).