# How to parse JSON into NSManagedObject with Codable?

Tags: json, swift, core-data, codable

My app receives data from the server, and I need to deserialize JSON. I’m used to working with structs which conform to `Codable`: in that case, I only have to specify `CodingKeys` when properties of my model have different names compared to properties in the server response.

Here’s a fully functional example of Playground code:

```swift
struct Country: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let phoneCode: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case phoneCode = "phone_code"
    }

    init?(from jsonString: String) {
        guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }

        do {
            self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: jsonData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let jsonResponse = """
{
    "id": 23,
    "name": "France",
    "phone_code": "+33"
}
"""

let france = Country(from: jsonResponse)
print(france?.phoneCode)
```

However, once I started implementing Core Data into my app, I had to convert structs to classes, so now the model for `Country` looks like this:

```
@objc class CDCountry: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var phoneCode: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case phoneCode = "phone_code"
    }
}
```

When I add `Codable` to type declaration, I get an error message saying the type does not conform to `Encodable` and `Decodable`.

What is the correct way to add `Codable` conformance to subclasses of `NSManagedObject` with a minimum amount of extra code?

Comment: https://medium.com/@andrea.prearo/working-with-codable-and-core-data-83983e77198e

Comment: https://medium.com/@kf99916/codable-nsmanagedobject-and-cllocation-in-swift-4-b32f042cb7d3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data