# Read from JSON or XML file and write into array of Core Data Objects

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, core-data

And I have created a Core Data Entity ("Exstand") that looks like the below JSON structure (same fields) and I try to read from the JSON file and write into an array of Core Data objects.

I have a local (stored in Xcode) JSON file that contains data looking like this:

```
[{
    "objectid": 13003,
    "lat": 40.198539203831054,
    "long": 20.294164128143816,
    "adresse": "1 Random Street
    "zeitraum": "v. 7-20h",
    "stellplatzanzahl": 3
},
{
    "objectid": 13004,
    "lat": 50.25018761410509,
    "long": 30.44382262875748,
    "adresse": "2 Random Street",
    "zeitraum": "",
    "stellplatzanzahl": 6
}]
```

I have went through many tutorials and posts here but can't for the life of me get it working for me because they either open a remote file and/or don't try to store into Core Data.

This is the code I have so far and it crashes when I try append the object to the array. When the .append line is commented I can see in the console that it doesn't actually write data into "stand".

```
class EventDetails: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var eventMap: MKMapView!


var annotation:MKAnnotation!

var Standarray: [Exstand] = []
var stand:Exstand? = nil
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    do {
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
        let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Nstand].self, from: data! as Data)

        for detail in jsonData {

            self.stand?.adresse = detail.adresse as String
            self.stand?.lat = detail.lat as Double
            self.stand?.long = detail.long as Double
            self.stand?.stellplatzanzahl = Int16(detail.stellplatzanzahl as Int)
            self.stand?.zeitraum = detail.zeitraum as String

            print(stand?.adresse)
            print("adressen!")
//The line below crashes the app Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            Standarray.append(stand!)                 
        }
        print("array!")
        print(Standarray)            
    } catch {
     print(error)   // Handle Error
    }        
    }
}
```

I also created this struct because in some tutorials they worked with that instead of Core Data entities, so if that is a better, I can also use that.

```
struct NStand : Codable{    
var objectid: Int
var lat: Double
var long: Double
var adresse: String
var zeitraum: String
var stellplatzanzahl: Int
}
```

I also have the JSON data in a XML file. I don't care from where to read it, all I want is my app to actually read and store the data.

Thanks in advance for any helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid here

> "adresse": "1 Random Street

to

> "adresse": "1 Random Street",

should be

```
[{
    "objectid": 13003,
    "lat": 40.198539203831054,
    "long": 20.294164128143816,
    "adresse": "1 Random Street",
    "zeitraum": "v. 7-20h",
    "stellplatzanzahl": 3
    },
 {
    "objectid": 13004,
    "lat": 50.25018761410509,
    "long": 30.44382262875748,
    "adresse": "2 Random Street",
    "zeitraum": "",
    "stellplatzanzahl": 6
    }
]
```

---

```
struct NStand : Codable{  // for core-data NSManagedObject
    let objectid,stellplatzanzahl: Int
    let lat,long: Double 
    let adresse,zeitraum: String 
}
```

---

```
        let str = """

[{
"objectid": 13003,
"lat": 40.198539203831054,
"long": 20.294164128143816,
"adresse": "1 Random Street",
"zeitraum": "v. 7-20h",
"stellplatzanzahl": 3
},
{
"objectid": 13004,
"lat": 50.25018761410509,
"long": 30.44382262875748,
"adresse": "2 Random Street",
"zeitraum": "",
"stellplatzanzahl": 6
}]


"""

        do {

            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([NStand].self, from: Data(str.utf8))

            print(res)
        }
        catch {

            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `stand` is `nil` and never gets created.

Adopting `(De)codable` in a `NSManagedObject` subclass is a bit tricky because you have to call the designated initializer which requires the managed object context.

Based on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data) by casademora first create an extension of `CodingUserInfoKey` and `JSONDecoder` to be able to pass the managed object context along.

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")!
}

extension JSONDecoder {
    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.init()
        self.userInfo[.context] = context
    }
}
```

Then add `CodingKeys` and the required initializer to your `NSManagedObject` subclass (in the class, not in the extension).

```
class Exstand: NSManagedObject, Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case objectid, lat, long, adresse, zeitraum, stellplatzanzahl }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("Exstand Error: no managed object context!") }
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Exstand", in: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let objectid = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .objectid) // do something with objectid
        adresse = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: . adresse)
        lat = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .lat)
        long = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .long)
        zeitraum = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .zeitraum)
        stellplatzanzahl = try values.decode(Int16.self, forKey: .stellplatzanzahl)
    }
  ...
}
```

Thats all you need, now you can decode the JSON directly into Core Data

```
var standArray = [Exstand]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let context = // here add the reference to the managed object context
        let decoder = JSONDecoder(context: context)
        standArray = try decoder.decode([Exstand].self, from: data)
        try context.save()         
    } catch {
        print(error)   // Handle Error
    }        
}
```

The other structs / classes are not needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to solve it with your suggestion- I couldn't get it to work. I had already spent several days on finding solutions and after trying yours I got frustrated and just uploaded the data to Firebase and was able to read the data via "(snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)". I don't understand why it's easier this way, but I haven't been programming for a long time as you can probably tell. Still thank you, and sorry for not using your suggested solution.