# App is terminating when trying to get an object value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My homework is to get a JSON array and save it to `CoreData` and then fetch it to a `UITableView`.

This is my first time working with `CoreData` and have already saved objects in `CoreData`, but when fetching I couldn't get an `Object` from the class I defined but instead I got `[NSManagedObject]`.
So I added `@NSManaged` on every field in my defined class, but then the app terminates.

Movie.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData
class Movie :NSObject, Codable{
    @NSManaged var title:String
    @NSManaged var image:String
    @NSManaged var rating:Double
    @NSManaged var releaseYear:Int
    @NSManaged var genre:[String]

    init(title:String, image:String, rating:Double, releaseYear:Int, genres:[String]) {
        super.init()
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.rating = rating
        self.releaseYear = releaseYear
        self.genre = genres
    }

    var title1:String{
        get{
            return title
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is supposed to be in Movie.swift, I looked it up online and I couldn't find much that could help.
Could it be that I need to add `NSManagedObject` instead of `NSObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues

- A class representing a Core Data entity **must** be a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. Let Xcode create the subclass(es) on your behalf.
- A custom `init` method cannot be used unless it's a convenience initializer calling [init(entity:insertInto:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506357-init) or other designated initializers.
- It's not trivial to implement `Codable`. Please see [How to use swift 4 Codable in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data)

For further information please read the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a core data model, Xcode can generate the model class for you. Open the `xcdatamodel` file and in the menu bar, go to `Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass`.[image: Menu option]