# Is it possible to reduce boiler plate code for swift codable protocol

Tags: json, swift, core-data, codable

Codable is great, its one of the only json parsing solution that allows your NSMangedObject models to be serialised back and forth to dictionary and JSON data respectively.

The only issue is that there's just a lot of boiler plate code involved as you have to provide an enum of coding keys along with encoding and decoding methods which you have to write for all of your properties.

Is there any way to reduce that boiler plate code. I have tried Mirror api to infer all the property keys and their types to dynamically generate encode and decode methods for codable protocol for any class that implements it. But Mirror api is not powerful enough as it fails to give correct class type at times and doesn't include information about NSManagedObject types at all.

Since, codable is such an integral part of regular swift use, i am wondering if something could be done to reduce to boiler plate code.

Comment: You do not need to write any code or include any coding keys unless your requirements are different from the default functionality. Maybe you should show some relevant code examples in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In `NSManagedObject` classes the `Codable` synthesized protocol extensions cannot be used.

The reason is you **must** call one of the designated `NSManagedObject` initializers to insert the new object into the managed object context.

Comment: It is possible to some extent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data

Comment: @MartinR I think the OP wants to use the synthesized initializer/encoder to get rid of decoding and encoding each property in code which is not possible in a `NSManagedObject` (sub)class.

Comment: You are right, it isn't that simple. – To be honest, it is unclear to me what OP actually wants.