# how to save array of model to core data NSmanagedobject?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I am working with a list of objects that are being added to core data NSManagedobject each time seperately - that works fine.

The issue I am facing when adding the swipe to delete feature, I need to delete the current saved array in core data & save the new complete array, not add them one by one. Here is the code I am using which does not work and I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            customers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            let customersPersistancy = CustomerModel(context: context)
            for customer in customers {
                customersPersistancy.name = customer.name
                customersPersistancy.age = Int16(customer.age)
                customersPersistancy.surname = customer.surname
                customersPersistancy.region = customer.region
                customersPersistancy.gender = customer.gender
            }
            //print(customersPersistancy)
            saveData()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

```
func saveData(){
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("data saved successfully")
        } catch {
            print("error saving context, \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Not only does that not delete the desired row but it actually duplicates the row multiple times which I don't understand why.

Comment: remove the entire `for` loop and you should be fine

Comment: Can you send the re-arranged code so I can better understand you?

Comment: removing the entire for loop means there is no reference to one of the array cells being modified so I can't understand how would that work.

Comment: Did you try it? The code looks so wrong and pointless, you create one object `customersPersistancy` and then you write the properties of each and every element in your `customers` array to that single object before saving it. What do you achieve with it?

Comment: I think I do not understand fully the logic behind how this NSManagedObject stuff works. As far as I know, it is already an array of objects that I created from core data types, so what I was trying to achieve was iterating through all of the array of my struct model and passing each and every object to the NSManagedObject one, therefore removing the deleted object from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. The method `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)` passes the current index path and you have to

- Remove the item from the data source array
- Delete the item in the managed object context
- Delete the row
- Save the context

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let item = customers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        context.delete(item)  
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)         
        saveData()
    }
}
```

Comment: at the row of 

context.delete(item)  

I get:

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Customer' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'

Comment: I assumed that the data source array is the 'NSManagedObject` subclass (which is the recommended design).

Comment: no, the data source array that fills the table view is from a struct model that I have created. 
I worked this way because I had to have a model which conforms to Codable protocol and there is no option to perform changes like that to core data models.

Comment: therefore, I am stuck now with a function that requires an NSManagedObject and I have my own model object and the indexPath, how can I bypass this issue ?

Comment: Refactor your design. You can make `NSManagedObject` subclasses adopt `Codable`. It's not trivial but it's possible.

Comment: where do I put the actually inheriting stuff - inside which of the 2 subclasses created by core data?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data