# Codable and NSManaged subclass with separate saving and decoding operations

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, codable

My requirement is that I will get some JSON data from the server and I need to decode it and **sometimes** save it to CoreData. This is to ensure that I don't need to keep 2 separate Models each for Decoding and CoreData but one that will handle both.

I went through a few threads related to *Codable CoreData* but what they offer is that everytime we are performing *Decoding*, the object gets saved to the CoreData(which first of all is not what I want and second it creates duplicate entries) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data)

I wanted something like *If you want to just decode the data, do this, If you want to save the data do this* but using the same Model type.

The code that I've been following :

```
public extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    // Helper property to retrieve the context
    static let managedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "managedObjectContext")
}

public class Employee: NSManagedObject, Codable {

    @NSManaged public var employeeID: Int16
    @NSManaged public var personalDetails: PersonalDetails?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case employeeID
        case personalDetails
    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        guard let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext,
            let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "DBEmployee", in: managedObjectContext) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode User")

        }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.employeeID = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int16.self, forKey: .employeeID)!
        self.personalDetails = try container.decodeIfPresent(PersonalDetails.self, forKey: .personalDetails)

    }


    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(employeeID, forKey: .employeeID)
        try container.encode(personalDetails, forKey: .personalDetails)

    }

}
```

Now my problem arises when I just want to *Decode the data and not save to Core Data*. Since I am just decoding, I will not assign any *managedObjectContext* but when decoder is called, it will look for context, will not find one and will crash

I was thinking of handling whether the *managedObjectContext* exists inside the `userInfo` of *decoder* and if not, just use normal decoder which we generally use for `Decodable` protocol but because of the `convenience init`, it won't allow me to leave without `self.init`.

Is there any workaround that any of you have worked upon ?

Comment: Not with a `NSManagedObject` subclass, it requires to call one of the designated initializers.

Comment: @vadian So there is no way to "Use one Model class for both save and decoding but not save and decode at the same time"?

Comment: You should probably use a protocol instead that both your NSManagedObject class and your Decoadable struct/class conforms to

Comment: No, the compiler throws an error if you don't call `init(entity:insertInto:` or `init(context:`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But that was the thing I wanted to avoid in the first place altogether, maintaining separate classes for both NSManagedObject and Decodable

Comment: @vadian Okay. But is there a way to do what I want to achieve? Maybe not my approach but some other method/approach that will get me what I want

Comment: Yes I know but this is one of the disadvantages with inheritance (NSManagedObject ), the strong coupling you get which kind of locks you into a specific design solution.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Okay. So there is no way to achieve what I want to achieve? Single class for both the operations?

Comment: As I said *Not with a `NSManagedObject` subclass,*

Comment: You can try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46917019/3687801)

Comment: @nayem You can check the last comment on that answer and will realise what my problem is

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution or workaround for this? I'd also like to be able to decode and not have it automatically added to the managed object context