# Avoid JSONSerialization to convert Bool to NSNumber

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have JSON data that I need to convert to `Dictionary` so I use `JSONSerialization` for that purpose but when I check the created dictionary, I can see that it converts the `Bool` to `NSNumber` (for property named *demo*)automatically

```
import Foundation

struct Employee: Codable {
    let employeeID: Int?
    let meta: Meta?
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let demo: Bool?
}

let jsonValue = """
{
    "employeeID": 1,
    "meta": {
        "demo": true
    }
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonValue.data(using: .utf8)!

if let jsonDictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String: Any] {

    print(jsonDictionary)

}
```

**OUTPUT**

> ["meta": {
>       demo = 1; }, "employeeID": 1]

Is there a way to avoid this `Bool` to `NSNumber` conversion or maybe convert `NSNumber` back to `Bool` using a custom logic ?

Comment: You can use the value with `let demo = meta["demo"] as? Bool`. However as you've created structs adopt `Decodable` to decode the JSON directly into the structs.

Comment: What are your `struct`s doing here? Are you trying to **encode** or **decode**?

Comment: @nayem My main task was that I am getting `Dictionary<String:Any>` from CoreData and I need to convert to `Decodable` type. For decoding I need to convert that `Dictionary` to `Data` which I will input in `JSONDecoder`. That's why I was going for `JSONSerialisation`

Comment: Why do you want to convert `NSManagedObject` subclasses to structs? You can adopt Codable in `NSManagedObject`

Comment: @vadian [Tried that, No luck so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405554/codable-and-nsmanaged-subclass-with-separate-saving-and-decoding-operations). That's why I had to resort to this approach

Comment: In your previous question you wanted to create Core Data objects (without inserting them) from somewhere. Here you write *I am getting `Dictionary<String:Any>` from CoreData*. This is completely different.

Comment: @vadian Here I have separate operations for save and fetch from Core Data and decoding is separate from that. Decoding works as usual. Saving and fetching is done as Dictionary Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For decoding I need to convert that `Dictionary` to `Data` which I will input in `JSONDecoder`

If that is the case, you would use the [data(withJSONObject:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data) method instead.

Below is how you would do that:

```
let dictionary: [String : Any] = [ "employeeID": 1,
                                   "meta": [ "demo": true ] ]
do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
    let employee = try JSONDecoder().decode(Employee.self, from: data)
    print(employee)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

**And I would think again if I really need the properties of the `struct`s to be `Optional`s.**

Comment: Could you please elaborate on properties of the `structs` to be `Optional` problem?

Comment: @inokey, this is out of scope of this question though, in short: ___introducing unnecessary optionals in the model types themselves introduces more Optional Handling cases throughout your codebase___.

Comment: so It's just that. While I agree in general, I still don't think that it's the rule but rather code organization preference. Thank you for reply.