# Convert Codable object to Dictionary without Bool turning to NSNumber

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I have a `Codable` object that I need to convert to `Dictionary` so I first *encode* it to convert it to `Data` and then use `JSONSerialization` to convert that `Data` to `Any` and then use `as? [String: Any]` to get the dictionary.

The conversion is successful but due to use of `JSONSerialisation`, `Bool` types are being converted to `NSNumber` but I want to retain the `Bool` value inside the `Dictionary`

```
import Foundation

struct Employee: Codable {
    let employeeID: Int?
    let meta: Meta?
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let demo: Bool?
}

let employeeObject = Employee(employeeID: 1, meta: Meta(demo: true))

do {
    let encodedObject = try JSONEncoder().encode(employeeObject)

    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encodedObject, options: .fragmentsAllowed) as? [String: Any]

    print(dictionary ?? [:])

} catch  {
    print(error)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> ["meta": {
>       demo = 1; }, "employeeID": 1]

*demo* property is being converted to `NSNumber` but I want to retain the `Bool` value

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Avoid JSONSerialization to convert Bool to NSNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59420274/avoid-jsonserialization-to-convert-bool-to-nsnumber)

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler That question was asked by me as well but it's completely different from this one. The only similarity was that `JSONSerialization` converted `Bool` to `NSNumber` there as well

Comment: I fail to see how this is any different than that question. What is the difference?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler In that question I had a `Dictionary<String,Any>` which I wanted to convert to a Decodable object. Here I have an Object that I want to convert to `Dictionary<String,Any>`

Comment: That's... not what I see? In both questions you are converting a `Data` to a dictionary, and in both questions you are asking how to prevent this conversion from turning a `Bool` into an `NSNumber`. I don't see anything in that question about wanting to take a dictionary and convert it into a `Decodable`.

Answer (score 2):

The `print` output is misleading. That's related to internal implicit bridging to `NSDictionary`

Although the value is printed as `1` the type is a boolean, see

```
let meta = dictionary!["meta"] as! [String:Any]
print(type(of: meta["demo"]! )) // __NSCFBoolean
```

---

Your concern is causeless because to get the value from a `[String:Any]` dictionary you have to cast the type anyway

```
let demo = meta[demo] as! Bool
```

Or you have to cast the dictionary to `[String:Bool]`

```
let meta = dictionary!["meta"] as! [String:Bool]
let demo = meta["demo"]!
```

Side note:

Declare struct members non-optional as much as possible, not the opposite.

Comment: See my main concern is that I save this inside CoreData and then fetch it back and decode it. Say this *demo* value is converted to `1` from `true` and saved inside CoreData for `demo`. When I fetch this data back from CoreData and feed it to the `Decoder` using `JSONDecoder` with model as `Employee`, it checks the type of *demo*, which as per model is `Bool` but as per dictionary received is `1` so type mismatch occurs and it fails

Comment: I don't understand. Please give a concrete example of the type mismatch failure. Once again: `print` outputs are not significant.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
struct Meta: Codable {
    let demo: Bool?

    public init(demo : Bool) {
        self.demo = demo
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case demo = "demo"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        demo = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .demo)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.demo, forKey: .demo)
    }
}
```

The JSON representation is still a number, but it decodes correctly back into Bool.

Comment: Consider that everything but the declaration line is synthesized so you can delete it. `struct Meta: Codable { let demo: Bool? }` does exactly the same so actually it makes no difference.