# Store Dictionary inside CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am getting some response for an API call from the server and I want to save that inside `CoreData`. Most of the fields are native type which *CoreData* accepts but one is a `[String:String]` which I have to save. I have gone through a few threads but most of them recommends me to make separate entities and I'm not so sure what should I declare inside my main Entity, what should be the type declared inside `.xcdatamodeld` file. Here's what the data looks like

```
struct UserInfo: Codable {

  let meta: [String: String]?

}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data

Comment: @vadian Sorry but I couldn't relate it somehow. There is no dictionary related stuff there

Comment: The related answer shows how to make `NSManagedObject` subclasses conforming to `Codable`. As you have to implement `init(from decoder` anyway you can process the dictionary there and map it to any type you need.

Comment: @vadian and what will be the type of the attribute inside the Entity ?

Comment: That's up to you. For example use a new entity as relationship and save the dictionary key as `name` and the value as whatever meaningful attribute (name).

Comment: @vadian Okay so what you're suggesting and from what I could understand - Make a new Entity `Dictionary` with 2 attributes : `name` and `value` and have a **one to many** relationship between the 2 entities ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean..

Comment: @vadian Alright, and what about when I want to fetch the Dictionary? Does CoreData manages that on its own ? provide some helper method or something ? Because I want to convert it back to this, `UserInfo`, model with that Dictionary inside the `meta` key

Comment: It depends. One way is to fetch the `UserInfo` item and get the data from the relationship.

Comment: @user121095 you can store the dictionary as data in coredata and at the retrieval convert data to Dictionary