# Can I use the same context for saving two entities in coredata?

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I don't know whether I describe the problem right, but here is my confusion: right now I have a json like this`

```
[
    {
        "title": "TextBook",
        "items" : [
            {
                "name" : "firstBook",
                "instore" : true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Charger",
        "items" : [
            {
                "name" : "firstCharger",
                "instore" : true
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "title": "Studyroom",
        "items": [

            {
                "name" : "firstStudyroom",
                "instore" : true
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "title": "Headphone",
        "items":[
            {
                "name" : "firstHeadphone",
                "instore" : true
            }
        ]
    }

]

`.
```

and I read it in my AppDelegate.swift file through JSON Decoder

```
       func parseJSON(jsonData: Data) {

        let context = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
        let contextForItem = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.context!] = context



            let decodedData = try decoder.decode([Category].self, from: jsonData)



            for category in decodedData {

                let newCategory = Category(context: context)
                newCategory.title = category.title
                if let itemArray = category.items {

                    for item in itemArray {
                        let newItem = Item(context: contextForItem)

                        newItem.name = item.name
                        newItem.instore = item.instore
                        newItem.parentCategory = category

                        itemData.append(newItem)
                        try contextForItem.save()
                        print(newItem.parentCategory.title)
                    }


                } else {
                    print("nothing in the set")
                }



                categoryModel.append(newCategory)


            }
            print(categoryModel.count)
            print(itemData.count)

            try context.save()


        } catch {
            print("error while decoding the JSON file, \(error)")

        }
    }
```

but when I load up my categories and items in my viewController with fetch request, I always find the number of categories, and the items will double and become 8. I want to know if it has something to do with the context? How can I load the correct number of items?  Here is the load function I used in the viewController:

```
 func loadCategories() {
    let fetchRequest = Category.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Category>

    do {

        print("before fetching \(categories.count)")
        categories = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("afterLoading \(categories.count)")

    } catch {
        print ("Error while loading Categories \(error)")
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()


}
```

Comment: Of course you can. Why do you use two contexts at all? And why do you parse the JSON in AppDelegate rather than in the `NSManagedObject` subclass(es)?

Comment: What do you suggest I do? Is the subclass you mentioned the one that is manually created? I'm so confused about this.  Thanks for answering me! @vadian

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data

Comment: Thank you so much! I've applied this code already, but I never notice that the context should be saved once the decoding process complete. I should not use two for-loops to specify each category and items datamodel, which probably duplicates the context again. I've solved the problem right now @vadian