# Custom Encoding/Decoding between CoreData and Struct

Tags: swift5, encoder, decoder

In my projects I two isolated modules, one covers the Networking part, that calls **Webservices** and the other one that nests **CoreData** object.

On the **Webservice** par I call my endpoints and uses `JSONDecoder` to map the server response to a corresponding `struct` like so:

```
public struct ObjectJSONStructure: Codable {
    var objectID: Int64
    var name: String
    var desc: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case objectID = "id"
        case name
        case desc = "description"
    }
}
```

everything works fine from there, but when converting this structure to a **CoreData** object (i.e. a class) and vice versa, I am doing it manually with custon `init`s:

```
// from CoreData to Object Structure
extension ObjectJSONStructure {
    public init(object: MyCoreDataObject) {
        glassId = object.id
        name = glass.name ?? ""
        desc = glass.desc ?? ""
    }
}

// From Structure to CoreData 
class MyCoreDataObject: NSManagedObject{ /* ... */ }

extension MyCoreDataObject {
    convenience init(objectStruct: ObjectJSONStructure, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        self.id = objectStruct.objectID
        self.name = objectStruct.name
        self.desc = objectStruct.desc

    }
}
```

So for now what I am doing is:

*Server Response*  < **Coder** > *ObjectStructure* < **Manually** > *CoreData Object*

Is there a way to take advantage of `CodingKeys` and this Encoder/Decoder mechanic to **Map** the `ObjectStructure` to `MyCoreDataObject` like so?

*Server Response*  < **Coder** > *ObjectStructure* < **Coder** > *CoreData Object*

`decoded = try ServerStructDecoder().decode(MyCoreDataObject, from: myObjectStruct)`

It would greatly reduce the amount of code I had to write for mapping almost 16 objects.

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data

Comment: @vadian on this post he merges the JSON decoding part into CoreData directly, which skips the need of the struct. I want to keep the in-between structure to really isolate the two processes. I need a proper way to bridge between this struct and the coredata object

Comment: There is no way with a *Coder*. Of course you can serialize the objects and deserialize them in Core Data but there is no benefit because you have to write the initializer anyway.

Comment: Even considering that the fields maps almost perfectly? There is no generic solution to map two entities using `CodingKeys`?

Comment: No, for example you cannot write a protocol extension because the `init(from decoder` method must be implement in the `NSManagedObject` **class**, it cannot be implemented in an extension.

Comment: @vadian understood. So I have to do all these `init`s implementations and it is an okay way to do so?

Comment: Yes, it is okay