# 'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, decodable

I'm working with CoreData and JSON parsing with Decodable following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data) and encountered an error at the end of the initializer saying `'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let managedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "managedObjectContext")!
}

@objc(Task)
public class Task: NSManagedObject, Decodable {
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case diff, title, desc, doc
    }
    
    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext else {
            print("Decode context error")
            return
        }
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Task", in: context) else {
            print("Decode entity error")
            return
        }
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        do {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.diff = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .diff)
            self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
            self.desc = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .desc)
            self.doc = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .doc)
        } catch {
            print("Decode key error")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If either of your guards fail, you'll return from the method without calling self.init. Those are the "paths" its referring to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably throw a custom error in `guard` statements instead of just returning. Also you should remove `do-catch` from decoder function calls:

```
enum ManagedObjectError: Error {
    case decodeContextError
    case decodeEntityError
}

required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    guard let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext else {
        throw ManagedObjectError.decodeContextError
    }
    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Task", in: context) else {
        throw ManagedObjectError.decodeEntityError
    }
    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.diff = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .diff)
    self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
    self.desc = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .desc)
    self.doc = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .doc)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As it notes, you haven't called `self.init` on all paths. For example, if `context` is nil, then you return without calling `self.init`.

If you want to exit this initializer without creating an instance, you'll need to throw an error, not just return.

Since this `init` throws, it also doesn't make sense to catch errors and then discard them. Just let them throw to the caller.

Comment: you were about half a minute faster than me :)

Comment: @gcharita You gave actual code rather than just describing it. That's the more useful answer.