# JSON Endoding and Decoding CoreData

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I am very new to Swift programming, but fairly competent in programming in other languages.

I have a project which uses NSPersistenContainer for CoreData. I would like to export and re-import the data using JSON or XML.

I can manually generate a CSV file, but that’s limited in its usefulness, so I would prefer JSON; XML if I have to.

Everything I’ve found is dated, and requires extending NSManagedObject and using Codable. I gather this would not apply if I am using NSPersistenContainer.

Is there anything built in to modern Swift, or how would I go about doing this?

Comment: NSPersistenContainer is there to simplify the creation/setup process ( NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, NSManagedObjectContext), so things you read about NSManagedObject and Codable are not dated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data

Answer (score 0):

`Codable` is the thing built in to Swift to do what you want, and extending or subclassing `NSManagedObject` is how you use it with Core Data. Using `NSPersistentContainer` is orthogonal to the question. You almost certainly want it but it has no bearing on JSON import/export. It’s there to set up Core Data for you but you still use managed objects as your data model. Core Data doesn’t have built in support for JSON; it relies on the existence of `Codable` to provide that.