# How to store data from json and from CoreData? SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I study SwiftUI and I have an interesting task.
I need to get data from a site and store it in CoreData. Then, I need to get them from CoreData and show it in my View if I don't have internet.

I created my data model:

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    struct Friend: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id: String
        let name: String
    }
    
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let isActive: Bool
    let age: Int
    let company: String
    let email: String
    let address: String
    let about: String
    let registered: Date
    let friends: [Friend]
    
}
```

This is how I get the data form the site:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    //@FetchRequest(entity: CDUser.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var users: FetchedResults<CDUser>
    @State private var users = [User]()

    // some code
    // .............

func loadData() {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://****************.json") else {
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                    
                    let decoded = try decoder.decode([User].self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = decoded
                        return
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Decode error:", error)
                }
            }
            
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

So now I don't know how to store a variable which will contains data from the site and from CoreData when it needed.

Can anyone give some advice?

[User entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUPOk.png)

[Friend entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUavL.png)

Comment: how does your core data data model look like?

Comment: @vincent Above I mentioned my entities "User" and "Friend"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data