# Swift. How to initialize the CoreData model with default values, for example, those that came from the backend

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The task is this. I have data that comes from the server. I want to initialize the default CoreData model with this data, for example:

```
@objc(UserEntity)
public class UserEntity: NSManagedObject {

required convenience init() {
   let coredataStack = CoreDataStack(modelName: "UserModel")
   let context = coredataStack.context
   self.init(context: context)
}
required convenience init(json: JSONData) {
   self.init()
   self.id = Int16(json.id)
   self.nickname = json.nickname
   self.firstName = json.firstName
   self.lastName = json.lastName
 }
}
```

Further, using this default model, I will fill in the data for example in the profile. But I also need to make sure that I can save this model in CoreData, read it, overwrite it. While it turns out to get them and fill out a profile:

```
self.currentUser = UserEntity(json: JSONData()).
```

The question is how to do the CRUD operation with it now. I want the data to be saved in CoreData and the next time the user gets it from it.

Comment: You could use `Codable`, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450114/how-to-use-swift-4-codable-in-core-data)

Comment: Thanks for your help. How to do parsing, I know, this is an abstract example. The question is how to store in CoreData a model that has been initialized by default

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you create a UserEntity object it is already in Core Data (or in your managed object context to be more precise) so all you need to do is to call save on your context, `try coredataStack.context.save()`

Comment: Tried and didn't work. After initialization, I tried to make a request, but the storage is empty. So I asked for help

Comment: Well your question is so vague that it's impossible to give some specific advice.

Comment: I get server data and update my UserEntity model. Then I can run it as UserEntity(json: DataJSON()) and everything will work. But at the same time, the data in the self-storage was not preserved. Even calling saveContext() in any places, the data is not fixed in a convenient way. I want to know how to get the data that populates the default model and save it correctly

Comment: Looking again I see a possible major issue with your code and this is that you create a new instance of your CoreDataStack in the init(). Although I don't know what happens in the init of CoreDataStack it looks wrong, normally a class like this is a singleton and is accessed using`.shared` so that you always use the same instance of your core data store and the managed object context.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, most likely this is the reason. I will definitely check this version

Comment: Then again, if you look at the question I linked to earlier you could have your UserEntity objects created directly while decoding and then you wouldn't need the extra step you are doing right now.